# csrf token using decorator is not working in Django DeleteView

Tags: python, django, vue.js, csrf-token

csrf token is not working I am looking for a reason.

error message is this

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

code is this

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.generic import ListView, DeleteView
from todo.models import Todo

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ApiTodoDelV(DeleteView):
    model = Todo

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("todo 삭제 실행 ~!")
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.delete()
        return JsonResponse(DATA={}, status=204)
```

html script code is this

```
            remove_todo: function (todo,index) {
                console.log("remove_todo()...", index);

                var vm = this;              

                axios.delete('/api/todo/' +todo.id+'/delete/')
                    .then(function(res){
                        console.log("DELETE RES" , res);
                        vm.todoList.splice(index, 1);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err){
                        console.log("DELETE ERR", err);
                    })
            },
```

do you know why or how to slove problem?